# DataGridView Edit Mode

Tags: .net, datagridview

Currently I have a .NET `DataGridView` displaying data from my source `DataTable` `dt`. I'd like it to be able to be edited so that when the user clicks into a cell and makes changes the changes will eventually get stored back into the `DataTable` source. So far I've tried:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```

But this won't allow me to edit anything in the table. Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this out in a project and the following works like a charm:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Int", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Double", typeof(double));

    var random = new Random();

    for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(random.Next(), random.NextDouble());
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
}
```

Nothing special done to the DGV. I just dropped it on the form from the toolbox. I did not pre-create DGV columns.

The best I can suggest for your situation is to try to reproduce the problem outside of your main solution. Try to replicate what you're doing elsewhere and hopefully you'll find the one thing that's tripping you up. If you do create your own DGV columns before databinding, make sure they aren't set `ReadOnly` either.

Comment: So I've tried this and it does work, editing is allowed. However, I'm loading my DataTable a bit differently. I first parse a CSV file then use the dt.load() method to get it all in there. Here's my code: 

using (CachedCsvReader csv = new CachedCsvReader(new StreamReader(FrontierDump), true, '\t'))
            {
                dt.Load(csv);
            }

            dt.TableName = "Frontier_DataTable";

            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.Sort = "order-id";
            dt = dv.ToTable();

I'm guessing it has something to do with the columns being loaded are readonly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want it to save to the DataTable (in memory on the machine the app is running on) , or the server?

If you mean the DataTable, and the DataGridView is bound to the table, it is happening automatically, you're just not seeing it.    You can see this by calling [GetChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2552649.aspx) on the datatable in the DataGridView's [RowLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowleave.aspx) event.

However, I'm guessing you REALLY mean you want to save it back tothe source database.  if I'm guessing right, see this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbide/thread/5f8741dc-5874-46e7-8665-6bda3674bafd

**Edit - added based on comments**

There are a few things to check and try.

First, just for fun, instead of EditOnEnter, set the EditMode to EditOnKeystroke.

Also check to ensure that the .Enabled property is set to true, and that it's not inside another control (such as a Panel) that has .Enabled set to false.

Also, ensure the ReadOnly property is set to false .

Also, CanFocus needs to be set to true.

Most of the things I listed are the default settings, so look for settings in the Properties pane that are bolded, which indicates that they are not the default property value.

Comment: As of right now, I am having trouble just simply editing the table through the DataGridView. The code above seems to not work. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: I think I'm definitely misunderstanding the question.  Are you saing that physically, when you click on a cell or tab over to it, it does not want to let you type, you have to pause and then click again? You want to be able to just type into it?

Comment: Can you edit the GridView contents, but the changes are not affecting the DataTable, or is the issue that you can't edit the contents of the control on the form, like it's disabled or something?

Comment: Like the editing is disabled. When I physically click into the cell it does not allow me to change anything. I'm assuming that once I edit this I can call the AcceptChanges method in the DataTable and the changes will be reflected there. I found this resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yztkd864.aspx and it specifies that the underlying data source must support editing. This is my next guess but I don't know how to make the DataTable editable through another source. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: The DataTable supports editing.  It doesn't apply to your situation.

Comment: Thanks, I tried everything you suggested and still no dice. If you can think of anything else that might work I'd love to hear it! Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Nope.  I'm at a loss.  I'd need to see the code (in Visual Studio in it's entirety) to play with it and figure it out from here.  I'm sure it's one of those things I'd be able to fiure out with my hands on it, but with the info I have now, I'm at a loss.

Comment: @Sam: This may be obvious, but are you sure the datagridview and its columns don't have the ReadOnly property set to true?

Comment: Yeah, just doubled checked to make sure it's not ReadOnly. This is confounding. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: When you figure it out (and I'm sure you will) please share.  My curiosity is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

In case you were using the designer there are three checkboxes which appear while configuring the Columns.
Allow Add
Allow Editing
Allow Delete
I presume you have checked none of them due to which the Grid is shown readonly to you.

Also do check if you have marked your columns as readonly.